There's a scene that something black (looks like humans) holding hands and dancing on the white screen

Year: Around 2006

I've seen this movie when I was 6 (in 2006) on the computer with my friend. So I don't really remember it and understand it because it was a western movie. 
I'll describe some scenes that I remember:

there was a woman and a boy (maybe mother and son) driving a car and suddenly there were foxes (or deer) jump out from the forest and jump on the windscreen.
in that boy's room, there's suddenly a creepy tree growing on the wall 
there's something black looks like humans hold hands to each other to make a circle and dancing on the white screen.


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I have proposed a few edits as I think I know the film you're after. But any further information will help with submitting a more detailed answer.

@tohood87 It's really not good to add details to an ID question. You could be completely wrong.

@Catija - I agree, I will request to remove the changes.

@Catija - my intentions were that the person asking the question could confirm the extra details. But someone else may have okayed it so I have reverted it back a bit. Hopefully, Rena can confirm if it's in Colour / English language etc. Apologies.

@tohood87 If you think you know what movie it is, put it as an answer, and describe why you believe it is the correct movie.

@BlueMoon93 - I have been told before to only submit answers to more detailed questions. Otherwise, they can be put on hold and removed later. But what the hell I have decided to post it anyway :)

@tohood87 It's a murky ground, that one. I'd tell you to post as a comment if you feel like it's not enough for a good answer. However, seeing as how the question didn't get closed and now even has a positive score, I think you're safe to answer it as usual.

I believe you're looking for the 2005 film The Ring Two.
This fits in with when you saw the film and matches key scenes you remember. At one point in the film, Rachel and her son are traveling in a wooded area when they're attacked by deers.
There is also a scene where the outline of a burning tree appears on the wall. I can't remember exactly what imagery is used but the dancing on a white screen would also fit with the killer video tape. This features creepy black and white visuals.
Screen shot 1 (Deer):

Screen shot 2 (Burning Tree):

Screen shot 3 (Dancing People):

Here is the trailer: 



If this is true, op has seen some messed up things at the age of 6.

I was thinking the same thing! - @PhilippFlenker added some extra screen shots.

@PhilippFlenker haha
